# How to subset a data frame by id, with sampling 1 row by id? (in R)

Tags: r

I have a big data frame and each row have an id code.
But i want to create another data frame with only one row of each id.
How can i do it?

This is one part of the data (the id column is "codigo_pon"):

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including data and your code which can be used to test and verify possible solutions. [Asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  group_by(id_column) %>%
  sample_n(1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, you could do somethink like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Example data

```
data <-
  tibble(
    id = rep(1:20,each = 5),
    value = rnorm(100)
  )
```

### Sample data, 1 row by id

```
data %>% 
  #Group by id variable
  group_by(id) %>% 
  #Sample 1 row by id
  sample_n(size = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### base R

```r
data[!ave(seq_len(nrow(data)), data$codigo_pon,
          FUN = function(z) seq_along(z) != sample(length(z), size = 1)),]
```

or

```r
do.call(rbind, by(data, data$codigo_pon,
                  FUN = function(z) z[sample(nrow(z), size = 1),]))
```

(Previously I suggested `aggregate`, but that sampled each column separately, breaking up the rows.)

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(data)[, .SD[sample(.N, size = 1),], by = codigo_pon]
```

(dplyr has already been demonstrated twice)